# Code is running without showing any output in emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

This is my 8086 code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
  original db 'abc world def world xyz',0
  find     db 'world',0
  subst    db 'cat',0
  result   db 100 dup(0)
  i        dw ?             ;INDEX FOR "ORIGINAL".
  j        dw ?             ;INDEX FOR "RESULT".
.code
   mov  ax, @data
   mov  ds, ax
   mov  i, offset original ;"I" POINTS TO "ORIGINAL".
   mov  j, offset result   ;"J" POINTS TO "RESULT".
;SEARCH VARIABLE "FIND" AT CURRENT POSITION ("I").
   mov  si, i
   lea  di, find
search:                        
   mov  al, [di]        ;CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "FIND".
;CHECK IF END OF "FIND".
   cmp  al, 0           ;IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
   je   match           ;... VARIABLE "FIND" WAS FOUND.
;CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
   cmp  [si], 0
   je   finale
;CONTINUE.   
   cmp  [si], al        ;CMP ORIGINAL[SI],FIND[DI].
   jne  mismatch        ;CHARS ARE DIFFERENT.
   inc  si              ;NEXT CHAR OF "ORIGINAL".
   inc  di              ;NEXT CHAR OF "FIND".
   jmp  search          ;REPEAT (COMPARE NEXT CHAR).
match:
;WHEN "FIND" IS FOUND, "SUBST" REPLACE IT IN "RESULT".
   mov  i, si           ;SKIP "FIND" IN "ORIGINAL", BUT...
   dec  i               ;...SKIPPED ON CHAR FORWARD (SO DECREASE).
   lea  di, subst       ;STRING TO REPLACE "FIND".
replace:
   mov  al, [di]        ;CURRENT CHAR OF VARIABLE "SUBST".
;CHECK IF END OF "SUBST".
   cmp  al, 0           ;IF CURRENT CHAR OF "FIND" IS LAST ONE...
   je   next
;CONTINUE.
   mov  si, j           ;CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
   mov  [si], al        ;COPY CHAR INTO "RESULT[ J ]".
   inc  j               ;NEXT POSITION IN "RESULT".
   inc  di              ;NEXT POSITION IN "SUBST".
   jmp  replace
mismatch:    
;APPEND CURRENT CHAR (AL) INTO "RESULT".
   mov  si, i           ;CURRENT POSITION IN "ORIGINAL".
   mov  di, j           ;CURRENT POSITION IN "RESULT".
   mov  al, [si]
   mov  [di], al
   inc  j               ;"I" IS ALSO INCREMENTED 4 LINES BELOW.
;NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
next:
   lea  di, find        ;SEARCH AGAIN VARIABLE "FIND".
   inc  i               ;NEXT CHAR IN "ORIGINAL".
;CHECK IF END OF "ORIGINAL".
   mov  si, i
   cmp  [si], 0
   jne  search          ;REPEAT (SEARCH "FIND" AGAIN).
;END OF WHOLE PROCESS.
finale:
   mov  ax, 4c00h
   int  21h
```

Sir, this code is running without showing any output in emu8086.
I don't understand where is the problem in this code.

Comment: I do not see any output procedures in your code. Neither are there any BIOS or DOS interrupts (except for the EXIT call 4C00h), nor any references to the 0B800h text video segment. So how could there be any output!?

Comment: This looks overcomplicated.  Keep pointers in registers; that's what they're for.  Reloading the same pointers from static storage all over the place is totally redundant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, the program isn't even trying to print anything.  Use a debugger to see if it puts the right things in memory before exiting.